# jQuery show method not working in rails app

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5

(jQuery/Javascript newbie here)

Within my rails app, I am trying to see if the selected option in a dropdown menu matches the text "New Category", and if so, then I want a piece of html to show a new line for the the form where the user can specify a new category name.

In my class.coffee file I have this:

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  if( $('#category-select option.selected').text() == "New Category")
    $('#new-categrory').show()
```

In my class.html.erb file I have this:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 center block">
            <%= f.label :category, "Category" %>
            <%= f.select :category, options_for_select(getAllCategories), {}, {:required => true, :class => 'form-control', id: "category-select"} %>
            <%= f.text_field :category, :class => 'form-control', id: "new-category" %>
</div>
```

(where my getAllCategories function just returns an array of options, but that's not important)

and lastly I have a class rule in my class.scss:

```
#new-category{
display: none;
}
```

So I'm pretty stuck. I've tried using syntax from multiple stackoverflow question's and nothing is working yet.

I have been able to run a simple alert popup when the dropdown is selected, so I know jQuery is running.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it.

I ran it once the '#select-category' id got changed, so

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
    $('#category-select').change ->
        selected = $('#category-select').val()
        if selected is "New Category"
            $('#new-category').show()
        else
            $('#new-category').hide()
```

And that finally did the trick. Hope that helps anyone else running into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation in your coffeescript file might be the issue, try indenting the second line one level, for example:

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  if( $('#category-select option.selected').text() == "New Category")
    $('#new-categrory').show()
```

[Here is a link showing the issue with what you have now ---- NOTE: had use a weird link shortener because the coffeescript compiler was generating url that didn't mesh nicely with markdown.](https://v.gd/A3eT0t)

Comment: It is indented in my code, it just didn't appear correctly when I copied it over